# Commonly identifying the patterns in C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have two classes

```
public class ClassA
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string Countries {get;set;}
 public string City { get;set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string Countries {get;set;}
 public string Village{ get;set; }
}
```

These two classes are in another class

```
public class ComponentClass
{
   public List<ClassA> classAObj { get; set; }
   public List<ClassB> classBObj { get; set; }
}
```

The data for the **ComponentClass** is coming from third party where the data for **ClassA** and **ClassB** is similar in structure. **"City"** in ClassA will have data in comma separated values **"Manchester,Sydney"** etc similarly with Village as well with comma separated values.

Now I am building a customized object at business layer where I am iterating through each property of ComponentClass and extracting information.

```
Main()
{
  ComponentClass[] c = //Data from 3rd party;
  foreach(var data in c)
  {
    Parent p = new Parent();


    if(data.classAObj.count > 0)
    {
      Star s = new Star();
      s.Area = "infinite";
      s.Color = "red";
      List<string> sep = data.City.Split(',').Select(string.Parse).ToList();    
      foreach(var b in sep)
      {
       TinyStar t = new TinyStar();
       t.smallD = b;
       s.Values.Add(t);
       }
      p.Curves.Add(s);
     }


    if(data.classBObj.count > 0)
    {
      Star s2 = new Star();
      s2.Area = "infinite";
      s2.Color = "red";
      List<string> sep = data.Village.Split(',').Select(string.Parse).ToList();    
      foreach(var b in sep)
      {
       TinyStar t = new TinyStar();
       t.smallD = b;
       s2.Values.Add(t);
       }
      p.Curves.Add(s);
     }

   }
}
```

In the code above , the two if statements are doing exactly the same operation apart from property names "City" and "Village". I want to simplify this by making use of any design pattern possibly strategy pattern which I just know theoretically or any other patterns.

Here is what I have tried :

```
public abstract class Base
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Countries {get;set;}
}

public class ClassA : Base
{

 public string City { get;set; }
}


public class ClassB : Base
{
 public string Village{ get;set; }
}
```

I want to make it as a common factory method which will do the looping and build the object for me for avoiding duplication of the code

```
public void CommonMethod(Base)
{
  // How do I differentiate the properties for looping 
}
```

Comment: In what format you get data from `third party` ? Is it json?

Comment: Yes it is in json

Comment: Would it be an option to use reflection?

Comment: Yes anything which simplifies unnecesary looping twice

Comment: Can you share a sample portion of json?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Json is not significant here , the data for public string City { get;set; } and village will be in comma separated values "A,B,C" etc

Comment: It would so help if you had a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to reduce the code repetition, the two statements could be refactored into a single action as follows.

```
foreach(var data in c)
{
    Parent p = new Parent();

    Action<string> iAction = iString =>
    {
        Star s = new Star();
        s.Area = "infinite";
        s.Color = "red";
        List<string> sep = iString.Split(',').Select(string.Parse).ToList();

        foreach(var b in sep)
        {
            TinyStar t = new TinyStar();
            t.smallD = b;
            s.Values.Add(t);
        }
        p.Curves.Add(s);
    }

    if(data.classAObj.count > 0)
    {
        iAction(data.City);
    }

    if(data.classBObj.count > 0)
    {
        iAction(data.Village);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a same datatype properties for the both of the types in the json than you can create a single class to map it,

```
    public class ClassA
    {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Countries {get;set;}
     public string Areas{ get;set; }
    }


public class ComponentClass
{
   public List<ClassA> classAObj { get; set; }
   public List<ClassA> classBObj { get; set; }
}


Main()
{
  ComponentClass[] c = //Data from 3rd party;
  foreach(var data in c)
  {
    Parent p = new Parent(); 
    GetParent   (p ,data.classAObj )
    GetParent   (p ,data.classBObj )
   }
}

void GetParent (Parent p, ClassA classObj){
 if(data.classAObj.count > 0)
    {
      Star s = new Star();
      s.Area = "infinite";
      s.Color = "red";
      List<string> sep = data.Areas.Split(',').Select(string.Parse).ToList();    
      foreach(var b in sep)
      {
       TinyStar t = new TinyStar();
       t.smallD = b;
       s.Values.Add(t);
       }
      p.Curves.Add(s);
     }
return p ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest inheriting the `ClassA` and `ClassB` from a common base as you did and then casting them, after typechecking. If your only goal is minimizing code-repition this will get your there:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ComponentClass[] c = new List<ComponentClass>().ToArray();//Data from 3rd party;

        foreach (var data in c)
        {
            Parent p = new Parent();


            if (data.classObjs.Count > 0)
            {
                Star s = new Star
                {
                    Area = "infinite",
                    Color = "red"
                };
                foreach (var b in data.classObjs)
                {
                    string bStr = b.GetType() == typeof(ClassA) ? ((ClassA)b).City : ((ClassB)b).Village;

                    bStr = bStr.Split(',').Select(string.Parse).ToList();

                    TinyStar t = new TinyStar
                    {
                        smallD = bStr
                    };
                    s.Values.Add(t);
                }
                p.Curves.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    public class ComponentClass
    {
        public List<ClassObj> classObjs { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassObj
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Countries { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassA : ClassObj
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB : ClassObj
    {
        public string Village { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It might be necessary to refactor the tenary to `if...else` or `switch` depending on if you add more classes of type `ClassObj`.

Be warned though that `GetType` actually queries the assembly (at runtime) and should be used with caution from a performance point of view as it can slow down applications a lot when executed often.

Answer (score 0):

I have used reflection, check if it works for you

```
public static void CommonMethod(dynamic collection)
{

        Parent p = new Parent();
        Star s = new Star();
        s.Area = "infinite";
        s.Color = "red";
        foreach (var data in collection)
        {
            var properties = data.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                string propertytName = p.Name;

                var propertyValue = p.GetValue(data, null);

                if (propertytName == "City" || propertytName == "Village")
                {
                    List<string> sep = propertyValue.Split(',').ToList();
                    foreach (var b in sep)
                    {
                        TinyStar t = new TinyStar();
                        t.smallD = b;
                        s.Values.Add(t);
                    }
                    p.Curves.Add(s);
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ComponentClass[] c Data from 3rd party;
        foreach (var data in c)
        {
            CommonMethod(data.classAObj);
            CommonMethod(data.classBObj);
        }
}
```